# SQL Server not using available memory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, memory, hardware

SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows 2008R2 Enterprise

- Server has over 300 GB of memory but total memory use in control panel never goes over 86 GB
- Have SQL configured to use the maximum amount of memory
- Even under heavy use - CPU over 80% for minutes
- Dedicated SQL Server
- Several large databases
- One heavily used table has an index size alone of over 10 GB

Set the service account to hold locks in memory

Is that normal?

What can I test?

Can I get SQL Server to use more memory?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Standard Edition is [limited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143685%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to a 64 GB buffer pool.

To use all the available memory of the server, you'll need to upgrade to either Enterprise or Datacenter Edition, or scale out to multiple instances of Standard Edition.